# jquery each if value exists append to previous value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a list of events and venues which I am rendering in a google map. [see fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rf48gvz5/)

```
    var mylatlongs = [
                        {"confid":"1","venueid":"1","date":"2014-09-09","venue":"Venue 1","name":"Conference 1","lat":"34.042435","lng":"-118.266586"},
                        {"confid":"2","venueid":"2","date":"2014-10-10","venue":"Venue 2","name":"Conference 2","lat":"34.052778","lng":"-118.255833"},
                        {"confid":"3","venueid":"3","date":"2014-11-11","venue":"Venue 3","name":"Conference 3","lat":"34.050592","lng":"-118.242663"},
                        {"confid":"4","venueid":"1","date":"2014-12-12","venue":"Venue 1","name":"Conference 4","lat":"34.042435","lng":"-118.266586"}
                    ];
    var infowindow = null;
    jQuery(function() {
            var StartLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(mylatlongs[0]['lat'], mylatlongs[0]['lng']);
            var mapOptions = {
                center: StartLatLng,
                streetViewControl: false,
                panControl: false,
                maxZoom:17,
                zoom : 14,
                zoomControl:true,
                zoomControlOptions: {
                    style:google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.SMALL
                }
            };

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), mapOptions);

        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: ''
        });

        jQuery.each( mylatlongs, function(i, m) {
            var StartLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(30.984298 , -91.962333);
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(m.lat, m.lng),
                bounds: true,
                id : 'mk_' + m.confid,
                letter : m.index,
                map: map,
                title: m.name
            });

            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
                infowindow.close();
                infowindow.setContent(contentString);
                infowindow.open(map,marker);
            });

            var desc = m.date + " -- " + m.name;
            /*
            if (venueid already exists) {
            keep the one pin for the venue and append each name and date into the description seperated by a <br>
            }
            */

            var contentString = '<div id="content">'+
              '<div id="siteNotice">'+
              '</div>'+
              '<h1 id="firstHeading" class="firstHeading">'+ m.venue + '</h1>'+
              '<div id="bodyContent">' + desc + '</div>'+
              '</div>';

        });
    });
```

This works well except if there is multiple events at the one venue.
I have looked at clustering and Spiderfier which give the option to break out the pins into multiple pins, but what I want to do is in my contentString add each event in the one venue.

So with my example data
The popup description should have the below content.

```
    <h1 id="firstHeading" class="firstHeading">Venue 1</h1>
    <div id="bodyContent">
            2014-09-09 -- Conference 1 <br>
            2014-12-12 -- Conference 4
    </div>

    <h1 id="firstHeading" class="firstHeading">Venue 2</h1>
    <div id="bodyContent">
            2014-10-10 -- Conference 2
    </div>

    <h1 id="firstHeading" class="firstHeading">Venue 3</h1>
    <div id="bodyContent">
            2014-11-11 -- Conference 3
    </div>
```

At the moment it has two pins on top of each other and when you click on it you get the last rendered pin (the latest event).

Is there a way to do this within the each with js or does the structure of the data in mylatlongs need to change.

Comment: if it was me would map the data by venue with array of conferences in it. Plot markers by venue. Start right back at the data source either as you recieve it in browser or change structure at server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

possible approach:

1. create an object where you store the markers:

   ```
      var markers={};
   ```
2. When you store the markers inside this object use the venueid as property-name and store the desired properties as marker-properties, for the descs use an array:

   ```
    //inside loop:

      //when there isn't a marker for the venue
      //create the marker
      if(!markers[m.venueid]){
           //create the marker    
           markers[m.venueid]=new google.maps.Marker({
               position: new google.maps.LatLng(m.lat, m.lng),
               bounds: true,
               id : 'mk_' + m.confid,
               letter : m.index,
               map: map,
               title: m.name,
               venue:m.venue,
               descs:[]
           });
           google.maps.event.addListener(markers[m.venueid], 'click', function() {
               infowindow.close();
               infowindow.setContent('<div id="content">'+
             '<div id="siteNotice">'+
             '</div>'+
             '<h1 id="firstHeading" class="firstHeading">'+this.venue + '</h1>'+
             '<div id="bodyContent">' + this.descs.join('<br/>') + '</div>'+
             '</div>');
               infowindow.open(map,this);
           });
         }
   ```
3. push the desc to the `descs`-property of the marker:

   ```
    markers[m.venueid].descs.push(m.date + " -- " + m.name)
   ```

Result: [**http://jsfiddle.net/rf48gvz5/8/**](http://jsfiddle.net/rf48gvz5/8/)

Comment: i loved the way you did this "this.descs.join('<br/>')"